# SQL Query help - need to calculate statistics on one parameter based on another

Tags: sql, average

Here is my query.  I am trying to calculate average [Coat_Tank_Pressure] based on [Run_Number], so that my output from this query will be:

Each run last for 10 or more minutes, and data is taken every second, so I want to get the average of the coat tank pressure over the entire run.  I've been struggling with finding the correct syntax and where to put the average commands and how to get it to calculate the summary info for each run.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm an SQL newbie, so I'm not even sure what type of SQL this query builder is using!

[Run_Number]   [Coat_Tank_Pressure]

1.......................Average for all values during Run Number 1

2.......................Average for all values during Run Number 2

3.......................Average for all values during Run Number 3

4.......................Average for all values during Run Number 4

5.......................Average for all values during Run Number 5

etc

OK, updated the query as follows:

---

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF

SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(INSQL, "SELECT AVG([Coat_Tank_Pressure]), [Run_Number]
 FROM WideHistory

WHERE wwRetrievalMode = 'Delta'

AND wwVersion = 'Latest'

AND DateTime >= DateAdd(hh,-1,GetDate())

AND DateTime <= GetDate()

GROUP BY [Run_Number]")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `GROUP BY` Run_Number, and then display average, using `avg` function

```
    SELECT avg([Coat_Tank_Pressure]), [Run_Number]
    FROM WideHistory    
    WHERE wwRetrievalMode = 'Delta'   
     AND wwVersion = 'Latest'    
     AND DateTime >= DateAdd(hh,-1,GetDate())    
     AND DateTime <= GetDate()
    GROUP BY [Run_Number]
```

Comment: OK, I added in your suggestions, and updated my original post.  I still get a Query Error upon running it.  This is frustrating, as I'm not sure the specific SQL that is being used by this program!

Comment: I was able to finally get this query working - I had to replace the * after Select and set out the statistics I wanted to perform before calling the openquery portion.  And then put the group by and order by outside of the openquery. Thanks for your help though!